# how change textcolor editor in qt

Tags: qt, colors, qsettings

this is my syntax editor program i want to show keyword,classes,function and ...with Separate color i set the color in config file(with Qsetting) 
for example this in my config file :

```
FunctionColor=blue
```

an in my cod i read the the configfile:

```
QString FunctionColor=settings.value("FunctionColor").toString();
```

how i can set the color in this instruction:

```
functionFormat.setForeground(Qt::FunctionColor);
```

compiler gives error? what i must be doing????

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you provide clear snippet codes instead of the example instructions above. However, based on my guess, if you check Qt documentation,

```
setForeground
```

is taking QBrush type of parameter. That means, to get what you want probably, you need to add some logic to convert between the string value to the QBrush value, for example:

```
if (FunctionColor == "blue")
{
   functionFormat.setForeground(Qt::blue);    
}
```

See if this could fix the problem.